# Few photos of each Food. How to design model?

Tags: django, django-models

I need a few photos of each `Food`. How well design model?

This is my try, but it is not a good:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/images")

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    photo = models.ManyToManyField(Photo)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion ForeignKey will be better:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/images")
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food)

class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

bacause one photo is always for specific food

Comment: I want to use later AdminStackInline. Will it be possible?